# How to split web.config?

Tags: c#, web-config

I want to split web.config and take these settings in a external file.

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Home/ErrorPage">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Home/ErrorPage"/>
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/ErrorPage"/>
</customErrors>

<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="noreplay@company.no">
      <network host="smtp.company.com" port="25" password="" userName=""/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I use

```
    <appSettings file="my.config"/>
```

to have MY settings outside.

But what about the standard settings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many (though not all) of the sections have a `configSource` property, which you can use very similarly to how you use the `file` property of the `appSettings` section.

[More info at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx)

---

```
  <customErrors configSource="MyErrors.config" /> 

  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp configSource="MySmtp.config" />
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: Good solution. Thank you! Disadvantage is I have to create two config files for each setting.

Comment: Can `configSource` reference the same file for multiple sections, or is it necessary to create a separate file for each section?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate out some sections of the file, you can't take everything out into separate files.

You should also consider what you gain by doing this.

Comment: One thing gained is environment configuration without needing to create individual build configurations for each environment just to take advantage of web.config transformation (which is really an abuse of the system anyways). You can leave these specialized external config files on the environment system, and leave global configuration that may change from publish to publish in the main web.config.